NestJS & Stripe undefined rawBody
I'm setting up a Stripe webhook in my Nest.js application but encountering an issue with accessing the raw request body (req.rawBody). Stripe requires this raw body for webhook signature verification. Despite configuring rawBody as per Nest.js documentation (https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/raw-body), req.rawBody returns undefined, leading to a "Webhook signature verification failed" error from Stripe.
Here's a snippet of my webhook handler:
@Controller('panier')
export class PanierController {
  private stripe: Stripe;

  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
    this.stripe = new Stripe(this.config.get('STRIPE_SECRET'));
  }

  @Post('webhook')
  async incomingEvents(@Headers('stripe-signature') signature: string, @Req() req: RawBodyRequest<Request>) {
    const webhookSecret = this.config.get('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET');
    if (!signature) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Missing stripe signature');
    }

    console.log(req.rawBody); // undefined
    let event;
    try {
      // Construct the event using raw request body, signature, and webhook secret
      event = this.stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, signature, webhookSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      throw new Error('Webhook signature verification failed.');
    }
    console.log(event);
  }
}

In main.ts, I've configured the Nest.js application with rawBody: true:
app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    rawBody: true,
  });

Despite setting up rawBody: true in my application configuration, req.rawBody within my controller remains undefined. How can I properly access the raw request body to resolve the Stripe webhook signature verification error?

What is available to access in req? Or is the req variable itself undefined?

rawBody: true, should give access to req.rawBody of buffer type

Have you checked out the stripe-node GH Issue on webhook signature verification?  There are lots of tips in the comments.  This one seems applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78368645/nestjs-stripe-undefined-rawbody

@RyanM, you provided a link to THIS question. :-P So, yeah, clearly applicable though not helpful. :)

What worked for me is almost the same as you write - with "@nestjs/core": "10.3.9":
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { rawBody: true });
}

// Controller
@Controller('billing')
export class BillingController {
  @Post('webhook') webhook(@Req() request: RawBodyRequest<Request>) {
    return this.billingService.webhook(request);
  }
}

// Service
@Injectable()
export class BillingService {
  constructor(private readonly stripe: StripeService) {}

  webhook(request: RawBodyRequest<Request>) {
    Logger.log(`Received Stripe Webhook.`, 'BillingService.webhook');
    const header = request.header('Stripe-Signature') ?? '';
    return from(
      this.stripe.stripe.webhooks.constructEventAsync(
        request.rawBody,
        header,
        process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET,
      ),
    ).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        Logger.error(err, 'BillingService.webhook');
      }),
      concatMap((event) => {
        // Extract the object from the event.
        const dataObject = event.data.object;
        
        // ...

        return of({});
      }),
    );
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class StripeService {
  public readonly stripe: Stripe;
  constructor(
    @Inject(MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN) private options: StripeModuleOptions,
  ) {
    this.stripe = new Stripe(this.options.apiKey, this.options.options);
  }
}


export const { ConfigurableModuleClass, MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN } =
  new ConfigurableModuleBuilder<StripeModuleOptions>()
    .setClassMethodName('forRoot')
    .build();

